# Android- View count for Firebase Database does not stop at 1

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a view count for my app through firebase database.

My plan was to add onDataChange on onCreate and add a value to the view count in the database.

```
private int value =0;
sPost.child("viewcount").setValue(value++);
```

I am trying to just have the value go up once, but on the databse, the number just keeps increasing. I have tried to limit the number to one using For loops but had no success. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have a situation where setValue is itself causing a data change, so each onDataChange triggers another call to onDataChange?  If so, you need to store the viewcount somewhere else in the database.

Comment: No I don't believe so